# Follow a random sequence

Tags: php, mysql, web, random, sequence

I am developing a web app on PHP + MySQL and if possible I would like to implement a way to generate a number given a sequence with no pattern. Now, that said I can't think of a way to do it (I even think is not possible).

I've got a MySQL table full of numbers from 0 to 150 in a specified order, however the sequence of numbers doesn't follow any pattern, is totally random. I would like the app to read the input (all the stored numbers) try to figure out the pattern that the numbers are following (even though they are random) and generate what the next number of the pattern would be.

I don't think is even possible as I said, but I thought it's worth to give it a try!

Any ideas on how to approach this problem?

Comment: Perhaps an example would clarify... whats wrong with random numbers?

Comment: `select * from numbers order by rand() limit 1`

Comment: Yes, I know about just generating a random number. Perhaps I didn't explain myself. What I would like is to see if even there is not an apparent pattern, the app could recognize a pattern in the numbers stored and give the next number of the sequence.

Comment: Ohh if we are talking about truly random numbers, it is impossible and actually makes no sense. If we are talking about recognize a random pattern, it is possible, but can be a very hard task depending on the pattern...

Comment: You're going to write a stock prediction app - right? :-)